# jQuery Total and subtotal gives NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a total and subtotal table using jQuery but I get a lot of problems. The first problem, when I reload this page, the total and subtotals display `NaN` even though the values from the input have been entered by default.

The second problem, data in the second row and so on, still takes the price on the first row only.

What I want:

1. I want the total and subtotal to be calculated automatically at the
   beginning and can be changed in the future.
2. I want each Total to
   calculate the price of each row

This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $counter = 1;

    $('table#invoiceitems').on('keyup', '.quantity , .price',function () {
      UpdateTotals(this);
    });

    $counter = 1;
    CalculateSubTotals();
    CalculateTotal();
  });


  function UpdateTotals(elem) {
    // This will give the tr of the Element Which was changed
    var $container = $(elem).parent().parent();
    var quantity = $container.find('.quantity').val();
    var price = $('.price').html();
    var subtotal = parseInt(quantity) * parseFloat(price);
    $container.find('.subtotal').text(subtotal.toFixed(2));
    CalculateTotal();
  }

  function CalculateSubTotals() {
    // Calculate the Subtotals when page loads for the
    // first time
    var lineTotals = $('.subtotal');
    var quantity = $('.quantity');
    var price = $('.price').html();
    $.each(lineTotals, function (i) {
      var tot = parseInt($(quantity[i]).val()) * parseFloat($(price[i]).val());
      $(lineTotals[i]).text(tot.toFixed(2));
    });
  }

  function CalculateTotal() {
    // This will Itearate thru the subtotals and
    // claculate the grandTotal and Quantity here
    var lineTotals = $('.subtotal');
    var quantityTotal = $('.quantity');
    var grandTotal = 0.0;
    var totalQuantity = 0;
    $.each(lineTotals, function (i) {
      grandTotal += parseFloat($(lineTotals[i]).text());
      totalQuantity += parseInt($(quantityTotal[i]).val())
    });
    $('.totalquantity').text(totalQuantity);
    $('.grandtotal').text(parseFloat(grandTotal).toFixed(2));
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="invoiceitems">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Paper</strong>
    </td>
    <td><strong>Price</strong>
    </td>
    <td><strong>Quantity</strong>
    </td>
    <td><strong>Total</strong>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><strong>SUBTOTAL</strong>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label class="grandtotal"></label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Glossy Paper A5
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="price">15000</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="item[1][quantity]" class="quantity" value="1"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label class="subtotal"></label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Glossy Paper A5
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="price">20000</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="item[1][quantity]" class="quantity" value="1"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label class="subtotal"></label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `CalculateSubTotals`, `price` is a *string*:

```
var price = $('.price').html();
```

so

```
$(price[i]).val()
```

doesn't make sense - it's a plain string already, and can't be meaningfully wrapped in jQuery.

If you want to access individual `.price` elements, then use just `$('.price')`.

Also, the `.price`s are `span`s, not inputs - to get the text in a span, you should use `.text()`. Only use `.val()` to get text from input-like elements, such as from `input` and `textarea`:

```
var price = $('.price');
// ...
var tot = parseInt($(quantity[i]).val()) * parseFloat($(price[i]).text());
//                                                               ^^^^^^^
```

The same fix needs to be made to your `UpdateTotals` function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $counter = 1;

  $('table#invoiceitems').on('keyup', '.quantity , .price', function() {
    UpdateTotals(this);
  });

  $counter = 1;
  CalculateSubTotals();
  CalculateTotal();
});


function UpdateTotals(elem) {
  // This will give the tr of the Element Which was changed
  var $container = $(elem).parent().parent();
  var quantity = $container.find('.quantity').val();
  var price = $container.find('.price').text();
  var subtotal = parseInt(quantity) * parseFloat(price);
  $container.find('.subtotal').text(subtotal.toFixed(2));
  CalculateTotal();
}

function CalculateSubTotals() {
  // Calculate the Subtotals when page loads for the
  // first time
  var lineTotals = $('.subtotal');
  var quantity = $('.quantity');
  var price = $('.price');
  $.each(lineTotals, function(i) {
    var tot = parseInt($(quantity[i]).val()) * parseFloat($(price[i]).text());
    $(lineTotals[i]).text(tot.toFixed(2));
  });
}

function CalculateTotal() {
  // This will Itearate thru the subtotals and
  // claculate the grandTotal and Quantity here
  var lineTotals = $('.subtotal');
  var quantityTotal = $('.quantity');
  var grandTotal = 0.0;
  var totalQuantity = 0;
  $.each(lineTotals, function(i) {
    grandTotal += parseFloat($(lineTotals[i]).text());
    totalQuantity += parseInt($(quantityTotal[i]).val())
  });
  $('.totalquantity').text(totalQuantity);
  $('.grandtotal').text(parseFloat(grandTotal).toFixed(2));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="invoiceitems">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Paper</strong>
      </td>
      <td><strong>Price</strong>
      </td>
      <td><strong>Quantity</strong>
      </td>
      <td><strong>Total</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><strong>SUBTOTAL</strong>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="grandtotal"></label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Glossy Paper A5
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="price">15000</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="item[1][quantity]" class="quantity" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="subtotal"></label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Glossy Paper A5
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="price">20000</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="item[1][quantity]" class="quantity" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="subtotal"></label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: unfortunately the total price is still calculated from price on first row

Comment: Oh, both your `CalculateSubTotals` *and* `UpdateTotals` had that problem, see edit - just apply the same solution to the other function

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, You already got content of price in line `var price = $('.price').html();` Then why are you trying to get value in this line `$(price[i]).val()` ?

There is no `value` key to get, And input fields only have value attribute.
**Solution is,**

`var price = $('.price');`

AND

`var tot = parseInt($(quantity[i]).val()) * parseFloat($(price[i]).text());`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $counter = 1;

    $('table#invoiceitems').on('keyup', '.quantity , .price',function () {
      UpdateTotals(this);
    });

    $counter = 1;
    CalculateSubTotals();
    CalculateTotal();
  });


  function UpdateTotals(elem) {
    // This will give the tr of the Element Which was changed
    var $container = $(elem).parent().parent();
    var quantity = $container.find('.quantity').val();
    var price = $('.price').html();
    var subtotal = parseInt(quantity) * parseFloat(price);
    $container.find('.subtotal').text(subtotal.toFixed(2));
    CalculateTotal();
  }

  function CalculateSubTotals() {
    // Calculate the Subtotals when page loads for the
    // first time
    var lineTotals = $('.subtotal');
    var quantity = $('.quantity');
    var price = $('.price');
    
    
    $.each(lineTotals, function (i) {
      var tot = parseInt($(quantity[i]).val()) * parseFloat($(price[i]).text());
      $(lineTotals[i]).text(tot.toFixed(2));
    });
  }

  function CalculateTotal() {
    // This will Itearate thru the subtotals and
    // claculate the grandTotal and Quantity here
    var lineTotals = $('.subtotal');
    var quantityTotal = $('.quantity');
    var grandTotal = 0.0;
    var totalQuantity = 0;
    $.each(lineTotals, function (i) {
      grandTotal += parseFloat($(lineTotals[i]).text());
      totalQuantity += parseInt($(quantityTotal[i]).val())
    });
    $('.totalquantity').text(totalQuantity);
    $('.grandtotal').text(parseFloat(grandTotal).toFixed(2));
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="invoiceitems">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Paper</strong>
    </td>
    <td><strong>Price</strong>
    </td>
    <td><strong>Quantity</strong>
    </td>
    <td><strong>Total</strong>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><strong>SUBTOTAL</strong>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label class="grandtotal"></label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Glossy Paper A5
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="price">15000</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="item[1][quantity]" class="quantity" value="1"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label class="subtotal"></label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Glossy Paper A5
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="price">20000</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="item[1][quantity]" class="quantity" value="1"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label class="subtotal"></label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: but when I change the Quantity on 2nd row, it still take the price from the first row